# SQL update missing values from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have this table

```
----------  ----------  
jones       new york  
jones                   
richard     seattle
jones                  
richard                
Ellen       Vancouver
Ellen
```

And I want this new table

```
----------  ----------  
jones       new york  
jones       new york            
richard     seattle
jones       new york           
richard     seattle           
Ellen       Vancouver
Ellen       Vancouver
```

How can I update it? I am using Postgresql.

Comment: so basically wherever the 2nd field is empty, use the same value where it's not empty for the matching names?

Comment: Esssential information is missing from your question: Postgres version? Column names? Data types? Primary key? Table definition? Can there be various cities for one name? Describe the problem properly, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* solution would be to properly normalize the tables such that a one to one join table was created between them which joins each name to a single city, if indeed there should be exactly one city per name.

Given what you have though, you may supply a subquery in the `FROM` clause which returns the `MAX(city)` per `name` group. From there the `SET` clause updates the main table's `city` to the value returned by the subquery.

```
UPDATE 
  tbl t
SET
  city = c.city
FROM
  /* Subquery in FROM returns first (max()) non-null city per name */
  (SELECT name, MAX(city) AS city FROM tbl WHERE city IS NOT NULL GROUP BY name) c
WHERE 
  /* Only update non-null cities */
  t.city IS NULL
  /* Here's the joining relation to the subquery */
  AND t.name = c.name;
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6ad17/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a temp table that works.  You should be able to apply the same logic to your issue.

```
create temp table foo(employee_name text, city text);

insert into foo (employee_name, city) values
('jones', 'new york'),
('jones', NULL),
('richard', 'seattle'),
('richard', NULL),
('ellen', 'vancouver'),
('ellen', NULL);

update foo f set city = x.city
from foo x 
where f.employee_name = x.employee_name
and f.city is null;
```